# Как скрывать элемент в конце списка ListView

Tags: android, xml

Вместо фаб поставил изображение, и хочу чтобы в конце списка это изображение исчезало как фаб. Еще лучше чтобы это работало как в `ScrollAwareFABBehavior` с анимацией `R.anim.design_fab_out` и `R.anim.design_fab_in`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv_news"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout" />
</LinearLayout>


 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может кому пригодится решил так

```
  ListView listview;
ImageView fab;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_news);

fab = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fab);
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_news);

        listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
                        && (listview.getLastVisiblePosition() - listview.getHeaderViewsCount() -
                        listview.getFooterViewsCount()) >= (adapter.getCount() - 1)) {
                        animFab(0);
                }
                else
                    animFab(1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            }
        });


    }
    private void animFab(final float scale) {

        ViewCompat.animate(fab)
                .setInterpolator(AnimUtils.FAST_OUT_LINEAR_IN_INTERPOLATOR)
                .scaleX(scale)
                .scaleY(scale)
                .withStartAction(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (scale == 1) fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                })
                .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (scale == 0) fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                })
                .setDuration(250)   
                .withLayer()        
                .start();

    }
```

AnimUtils.java

```
public class AnimUtils {



    public static final FastOutLinearInInterpolator FAST_OUT_LINEAR_IN_INTERPOLATOR
            = new FastOutLinearInInterpolator();



}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Повесьте слушатель скрола на ListView
2. В нём отследите момент прокручивания списка до низу.
3. Примените анимацию и исчезновение к своей картинке

Comment: Можете написать как это сделать

Comment: @Артем, так я ж уже написал...

Comment: ваш ответ наверно самый очевидный, я и так давно копаю в этом направлении.

Comment: @Артем, и что вы накопали? Судя по вопросу вы лишь заменили FAB на imageView

Comment: Да извините скоре всего моя вина, в следующий раз я буду задавать вопросы более конкретно. Мне нужен был пример решения моей проблемы, а не советы что мне использовать